# Using several different modals

Tags: javascript, html, css

I followed [this guide](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp) to create a good-looking CSS modal with javascript. On my page, I have a total need of 8 different modals. Is it possible to use the same ID's and such? I know I have to fix some stuff in the Javascript, but I don't know how. The only way I see now, is use unique ID's and just duplicate the Javascript and change the variables to the IDs.

But there must be a better way, doesn't it? That way I can do this:

```
<a id="myBtn" class="modalBtn">Button one</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h2>Button one header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Button one text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a id="myBtn" class="modalBtn">Button two</a>
<div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h2>Button two header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Button two text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and having them show correctly. Instead of doing this:

```
<a id="myBtn1" class="modalBtn">Button one</a>
<div id="myModal1" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h2>Button one header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Button one text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<a id="myBtn2" class="modalBtn">Button two</a>
<div id="myModal2" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <h2>Button two header</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Button two text</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I do it by the 2nd example; then I have to duplicate the Javascript to make it have 8 variables for each button and each modal. There must be a easier, more clean, way of doing this.

Anyone know how I can achieve this?

Comment: In your examples there is no difference in content, or amount of code. You only updated IDs?

Comment: @Armin Exactly, the ID's needs changing in the second example, didn't post the javascript since it was kind of self explanatory imo. The javascript is over at the guide I linked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fundementally, Id's have to be unique.
If you'r worried about the javascript though, you could encapsulate your function have have take the id as a parameter.
ie-

```
function ModalFunction(modalId, btnId){
  // Get the modal
  var modal = document.getElementById(modalId);

  // Get the button that opens the modal
  var btn = document.getElementById(btnId);

  // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
  var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

  // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
  btn.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "block";
  }

  // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
  span.onclick = function() {
      modal.style.display = "none";
  }

  // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
  window.onclick = function(event) {
      if (event.target == modal) {
          modal.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
}
```

and then call it like so:

```
ModalFunction("myModal1", "myBtn1");
ModalFunction("myModal2", "myBtn2");
```

You can see a working jsfiddle (with some extras) here- https://jsfiddle.net/Lcmffb2b/2/

Comment: While this is a well explained answer, I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. I only want basic modals, with text-only inside. Doesn't this act with images and such?

Comment: @Condolent that was the function you've linked to.  If you want to use something less elaborated the same princeples still apply- you can encapsulate and move the needed parameters as variables.

Comment: Damn, I'm so dumb.. I linked the wrong guide, sorry.. Updated the OP

Comment: @Condolent no worries  :)  updated my answer with the new function

Comment: The code works, I'm calling it by `<a id="myBtn" class="modalBtn" onclick="ModalFunction('myModal', 'myBtn');">Button one!</a>` that's correct, right? A slight issue though, the span.onclick function only works on the default modal. (myModal) and not myModal1. Also it seems like I have to double-click the links for them to show up

Comment: @Condolent I see where the issue comes in- whenever span is clicked, only the last modal is closed, because the onclick event overrides the previous one.
You can fix this by also having the span with an id, or- just closing all the modals whenever span is clicked (ie- select all modals, and set them to hide one by one)

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it close all modals. I have minimum experience in Javascript

Comment: EDIT: I don't think that it closes the previous one. It only works on one single link. It's the one with a ID without a number

Comment: @Condolent I've added a JSFiddle to the comment, you can take a look there (the clicking on the window wont work in JSFiddle but should work in actual use)  good luck!

Comment: Thank you! It works gorgeously!! But it doesn't work to click outside the box to remove it. Expected it to not work in jsfiddle as you mentioned, but it doesn't work on my page either